# Rubymine Error Saving System Information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

I have Rubymine v. 7.0.4 and receive this error.
What could cause the problem?

[image]

Comment: @GSerg That's what is shows. I do not know the cause. Maybe some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like some application has exclusive access to this file.

If you are using any antivirus try to add RubyMine to exception list. In this case antivirus will not check RubyMine activity and probably will not lock RubyMine files.

Comment: Done. Now I'll check if the problem still appears.